# Haskell sublists

Tags: haskell

I have to make a function that finds specific sublists.

```
function :: Integer -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
function n m = …
```

- If `m` is smaller then `n` the program exits.
- If the `(mod (sum [1..n]) m) /= 0` then again error.
- Otherwise the program should find sublists.
- And the primary list is generated from `[1..n]`

For example, if the numbers are `n = 6` and `m = 7`. List is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` The answer is `[[6,1],[5,2],[4,3]]`.

```
function 6 7
>>> [[6,1],[5,2],[4,3]]
```

Order is not necessary. So on I have made these steps. Any help would be useful.Also example codes would be useful. If anyone can solve this problem, I would appreciate it. Code with solution would be very useful for me.

```
    function :: Integer -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
    function n m 
      |m < n = error "m is smaller than n"
      |(mod (sum [1..n]) m) /= 0 = error "list sum doesn't devide with m"
      |otherwise = …
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more detailed how the sublists are found - the example seems to be generated by `6+1=7,5+2=7,4+3=7` is this a correct guess?

Comment: each sublist are found as sums. each sum must be equal to 7 in this example. And also each number must exist one time at a sublist. so in this example we have sublists which contain from 2 arguments. For example if we wanna make 3 argument list such as [1,2,4], we can't, because we already have sublists which contain these numbers. Each sublist must be presented one time maximum. [2,5] and [5,2] are equal. So each sublist sum must be equal to m.

Answer (score 1):

I would go and create all lists with sum property, for example using list comprehension. And then filtering by the uniqueness property, by something like:

1. taking list difference of the first sublist and the generatorlist and checking if the next sublist is contained in the generator,

   - then deleting a sublist if it is not subset of the altered generator
   - or doing the same procedure as in 1.
2. you can end the procedure if the sum of the altered generators is less than m

note that the result is depending on how you have sorted all sublists - so the solution is not a unique longest list of sublists, but just one of many results possible with sum and "uniqueness" property.

---

### Edit: Some Code - not perfect maximum solution

just something to start and think about i only collect easy two element lists and otherwise take one maximal list.

The next improvements would be to make a function collecting not only easy but all two element lists and then generalize this to get sublists of a given length, maybe you want to have a look a bit at elementary combinatorics.

```
module Sublists where
import Data.List ((\\))

subLists :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
subLists n = subLists' ([],[1..n])

subLists' :: ([[Int]],[Int]) -> Int -> [[Int]]
subLists' aa m = fst (mLSubLists (tLSubLists aa m) m)

_subLists :: ([Int] -> Int -> [Int]) -> ([[Int]],[Int]) -> Int -> ([[Int]],[Int])
_subLists _ yx@(_,[ ]) _ = yx
_subLists _ yx@(_,[_]) _ = yx
_subLists f yx@(yy,xx)  m | sum xx < m = yx
                       | otherwise  = if tt == []
                                        then yx
                                        else _subLists f (tt:yy,xx\\tt) m
                       where tt = f xx m

tLSubLists :: ([[Int]],[Int]) -> Int -> ([[Int]],[Int])
tLSubLists = _subLists twoList

mLSubLists :: ([[Int]],[Int]) -> Int -> ([[Int]],[Int])
mLSubLists = _subLists manyList


twoList :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
twoList [ ]    _ = []
twoList [_]    _ = []
twoList xx@(x:xs) m | (x + l) < m         = []
                    |  x == l              = []
                    | (x + l) `rem` m == 0 = [x,l]
                    | otherwise           = twoList ii m
                    where l  = last xs
                          ii = init xx

manyList :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
manyList xx m | s < m         = []
              | s == m         = xx
              | s `rem` m == 0 = xx
              | otherwise     = manyList xs m
              where s  = sum xx
                    xs = tail xx
```

and some test cases:

```
import Sublists
import Test.HUnit
import Data.List ((\\))

main = testAll

testAll = runTestTT $ TestList tests

tests :: [Test]
tests = [
   "n=6 m=7" ~: "subLists"  ~:  [[3,4],[2,5],[1,6]]
                            ~=? subLists 6 7,
   "n=6 m=7" ~: "twoList"   ~:  [1,6]
                            ~=? twoList [1..6] 7,
   "n=6 m=7" ~: "twoList"   ~:  [2,5]
                            ~=? twoList ([1..6]\\[1,6]) 7,
   "n=6 m=7" ~: "twoList"   ~:  [3,4]
                            ~=? twoList (([1..6]\\[1,6])\\[2,5]) 7,
   "n=6 m=7" ~: "manyList"  ~:  [2,3,4,5]
                            ~=? manyList [1..5] 7,
   "dummy"   ~: "dummy"     ~:  "result"
                            ~=? (\_ -> "result") "function"
                            ]
```

Comment: Could you give a statrting point with a code ? Don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

The function `subsequences` in `Data.List` might be helpful, e.g.

```
subsequences "abc" == ["","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc"]
```

Then you "just" need to filter out all sub-lists that don't match your criterias.

Comment: Now I made that kind of success that I get lists with sum equal to m. But sub-lists still contain similar numbers. for example right now I get [[1,2,4],[3,4],[2,5],[1,6]]. Each number must be represented one time. Trying to puzzle that out. But it was useful tip. Thanks

Comment: @KasparKohler Are you aware that creating all sublists is exponential? That method would only work for small `n`.

Comment: Did not know that. But for first I would like to make it work with subsequences.

Comment: Seems like the subsequences isn't that useful, because it takes a lot of time to great sub-lists. Anyone has another solution idea?

Comment: I'd try to find a "slow" solution with `subsequences` first, and then write my own version (which avoids the generation of unnecessary sublists, e.g. where the sums are too big)